# I need to display only one part of a JSON encoded object

Tags: php, json, object

Hi I am new to PHP but have managed to get this far in my requirements:

I am trying to display only one part of a JSON decoded Object. I have called the object `$Results`.

I can successfully use `var_dump ($Results);` and then get the full results as follows:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public '0' => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'forename_1' => string 'JAMES' (length=5)
      public 'middle1_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'middle2_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'middle3_1' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'surname_1' => string 'TURNER' (length=7)      
  public 'Status' => int 100
```

I then insert this into a table using the following code:

```
<html>
<form id="client-details" action="/details.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
             <th>Search</th>  
        </tr>
     </thead>
<?php foreach($Results as $o):?>
<tr>
  <td id="forename"><?= $o->forename_1 ?></td>
  <td id="surname"><?= $o->surname_1 ?></td>
  <td><button type="submit" >More Info</button></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table></form>
</html>
```

**Heres the Problem**
When I display the results I get the following error:
"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.."

This seems to be because I am trying to run the `public 'Status' => int 100` part of the object.

So my question is:
How do I either stop the table from trying to populate that 'status' or how do I ignore it completely?

EDIT:
If I wanted to I could get the results from the `json_decode` as an associative array instead of as objects... would this help me to ignore the 'status' array/object?

Comment: Look the code when you fetch your results

Comment: your `var_dump` simply shows `$Result` has another object at `0` so you can not access like this

Comment: @wilson - I checked the Code when I fetch the results:     `$Results = json_decode($Results);` What I could also do is return the JSON as an associative array by saying `$Results=json_decode($Results, true);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got it wrong. What you are doing is iterate throught all variables of the object, i.e. firstly you get the public variable 0 (which is also an object) and in teh second run of the statement foreach you get the variable Status and because the value of 'Status' is int and has no property named 'forename_1' and so on you get the error that the property doesnt exist.

If you really want this to work you have to change the structure of the JSON object so you can iterate throught the list of people you want to display, like:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'list' => 
    array(0 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'forename_1' => string 'JAMES' (length=5)
          public 'middle1_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'middle2_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'middle3_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'surname_1' => string 'TURNER' (length=7)      
          public 'Status' => int 100,
        1 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'forename_1' => string 'JAMES' (length=5)
          public 'middle1_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'middle2_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'middle3_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'surname_1' => string 'TURNER' (length=7)      
          public 'Status' => int 100,
        2 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'forename_1' => string 'JAMES' (length=5)
          public 'middle1_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'middle2_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'middle3_1' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'surname_1' => string 'TURNER' (length=7)      
          public 'Status' => int 100
    )
```

EDIT:

if you are unable or dont want to change the data structure then get the result of the function call json_decode as an associative array and in the foreach statement you then check if the required field exists:

```
$Result = json_decode($data, true);

<?php foreach($Results as $o):?>
    <?php if(isset($o['forename_1']) && isset($o['surname_1'])): ?>
        <tr>
          <td id="forename"><?= $o['forename_1'] ?></td>
          <td id="surname"><?= $o['surname_1'] ?></td>
          <td><button type="submit" >More Info</button></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This is a very useful comment! in my specific instance, I cannot do this though :( --- I get the object directly from a suppliers webservice and I dont want to rebuild any data or results before I use them.

Answer (score 1):

I found an acceptable solution!
By adding `true` inside my json_decode line:

```
$Results = json_decode($serviceResponse, true);
```

I return the result as an **associative array** instead of an object.

I then changed the code inside each `<tr>` as follows:

```
<html>
.... (rest of code here)
<?php foreach($Results as $person):?>
         <tr>
           <td id="forename"><?= $person['forename_1'] ?></td>
           <td id="surname"><?= $person['surname_1'] ?></td>
           <td><button type="submit" >More Info</button></td>
         </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
     </table>
   </form>
</html>
```

So now what happens is that the final line `'status'` which was returning an Error is now just an empty row.
While this isn't a perfect solution, I don't mind dealing with an empty table row when I view the page as HTML.

Comment: You can bypass that with this if statement: "if(isset($person['forename_1']) && isset($person['surname_1']))" then display the row, else dont do anything

Comment: I tried that - didn't work... maybe I was putting the code in the wrong place.. I'm learning here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <form id="client-details" action="/details.php" method="post">
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                 <th>Search</th>  
            </tr>
         </thead>
    <?php foreach($Results as $o=>$v){?>
    <tr>
      <td id="forename"><?= $v->forename_1 ?></td>
      <td id="surname"><?= $v->surname_1 ?></td>
      <td><button type="submit" >More Info</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table></form>
    </html>
```

Comment: I tried this - no luck - The 'status' keeps trying to iterate

Answer (score 0):

Try to print like this:

```
<?php foreach($Results as $o):?>
<tr>
  <td id="forename"><?= $o['forename_1']; ?></td>
  <td id="surname"><?= $o['surname_1'] ?></td>
  <td><button type="submit" >More Info</button></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```